# Ruby Syntax Error: File Copying

Tags: ruby, file, syntax, copy

Coding a small script to copy some files, however I get the error:

> fileops.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Heres my code

```
require 'ftools'

plays = ['RomeoAndJuliet.txt', 'Hamlet.txt', 'TheTempest.txt', 'TheMerchantofVenice.txt', 'AMidSummerNightsDream.txt']

plays.each do |filename|
  File.new("/clean/_cleaned" + filename, w+)
  File.syscopy(filename, "/clean/_cleaned" + filename)
end
```

All the brackets appear to be where they should be. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

w+ should be in quotes.

```
File.new("/clean/_cleaned" + filename, "w+")
```

Comment: Thanks :) Still a Ruby beginner :)

Comment: Not a problem. We've all been there.

Comment: Hrm, this code doesnt seem to work at all, is there a better, correct way to do what I am trying?

Comment: You can do what @Veger suggested.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Fileutils.cp](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/FileUtils.html#M004324) to copy a file:

```
require 'fileutils'
Fileutils.cp source, dest
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'fileutils'
plays = %w[RomeoAndJuliet Hamlet TheTempest TheMerchantofVenice AMidSummerNightsDream]
plays.each do |play|
  Fileutils.cp "#{play}.txt", "/clean/_cleaned#{play}.txt"
end
```

Or, to copy all .txt files in the directory, instead of an explicit list:

```
Dir['*.txt'].each do |file|
  Fileutils.cp "#{file}", "/clean/_cleaned#{file}"
end
```

Comment: I took the liberty to fix your second example. `file` contains the compelete file name, so no need to add the `.txt` in the second after `#{file}`.